# Is consuming of a web service possible only when we are using MVC framework?

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller

Suppose  I want to consume a web service,  say   https://openweathermap.org/api  in my web application project.  Then does it requires that I have followed MVC architecture, meaning is consuming a web service possible only when we have followed MVC? I am thinking of the answer as yes because the implementation of this service can't be done by me. So not using MVC is not an option here.

Comment: Completely irrelevant. MVC is just a pattern. Your app"s architect is completely orthogonal to consuming web services. Might make parts of it *easier*, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, for communicating with web service you don't want to follow any software architecture.you can send GET,POST,PUT,DELETE etc. requests from your client application using any software architecture. there is no connection between software architecture of the client application and calling web services.for example here is a php file which sends GET request to given URL.(get data from api)

```
    <?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'Your URL');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $Response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    var_dump($Response);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The core principle of a web service is that it offers some services to multiple different clients (i.e external projects) through a public interface, but by hiding its implementation details . So the web service consumers (i.e the clients applications) know how to use the web service, but not necessarly how it has been developed. So whatever your application architecture is (MVC or not), you just have to follow the web service contract to request its services.